# Why I am getting error 500 when posting text with word the "from"?

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have this CRM that I built and the user can enter notes, but one of the notes won't save, returning an error 500. I checked the error log and there is no record of that error. The process is simple, it is a AJAX request that get's the text from a textarea and sends it to a PHP code to save the note into a MySql.

The funny thing is that if change the word "from" to "fro m" (with a space) it works. But if I remove the space, I get the error 500 again and no log information.

Also if I try it multiple times my IP gets blocked by my server's Firewall.

This is the note:

5/9/2019 Territory: ORIGIN: AB CITIES selected by the customer specifically DESTINATION: AB Cities selected specifically by customer. DO NOT EXCEPT any out of territory disputes from this account unless the city is not listed. He knows he can call in to adjust territory but will not receive credit for any cities he is removing. Lead Price: $6.00 USD Recurring: $200.00 Initial Charge: $300.00 USD. Customer understands the policy. TEST lead has been sent to him. Waiting for ED to work on final cities for origin. JH

```
$.ajax({
         url: "scripts/provider_note_add.php",
         type: "POST",
         data: 'provider_note='  + $("#provider_note").val(),
         success: function( data ) {
                  $("#result_notes").html(data).fadeTo(500, 1);
         }
});
```

Comment: Show us the PHP handler code. Most likely you have a problem with SQL injection.

Comment: "from" being an SQL keyword hints at the problem being related to your database code, which you should add to the question.  If you correctly enable php error reporting you will get a detailed error report.

Comment: check your error.log, you can find error.log in your root directory

Comment: I thought about  it being a MySQL word, so I remove the MySQL injection and I put a small code to email me the text (see below) . And I still get the error 500

$provider_note = addslashes($_REQUEST['provider_note']);

mail("xxx@yyyy.com","Note Add", $provider_note);

Comment: I ran another test, I changed the PHP handler to an empty PHP file (just a <?php) and I still get the error 500. This is so odd.

Comment: The error log is empty. No records.

Comment: UPDATE: I changed the PHP handler to search for "fro m" and replace for "from". So the as a temporary solution the user has to input "fro m" and then the PHP handler will fix it and save on the database. This is so weird. Not proud. Need to find out what is happening.

Comment: Have you tried turning apache security mod off?